# Struts2 : internationalize s:date?

Tags: struts2, internationalization

`<s:date name="mydate" format="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" />` works perfectly for fomatting my date to the french standard.
But It's hard-written in my jsp. So I have to build if clause to switch according to the locale.

**Is there a way to put this format to a general property file?**

I tried:

```
format.date = {0,date,dd/MM/yyyy}
format.time = {0,time,HH:mm}
```

put in my global .properties but it's not taken into account when, I try just a `<s:date name="mydate">` or a `<s:property value="mydate"/>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create localized date format inside your properties files, e.g. with `struts.date.format` key:

```
struts.date.format = dd.MM.yyyy
```

And use `getText` method to get this date format in `<s:date>` tag `format` attribute:

```
<s:date name="date" format="%{getText('struts.datetime.format')}"/>
```

Comment: This solution will not work for formats like "d. MMM yyyy". The month name gets set to what ever locale server happens to use.

Comment: @Bloodboiler: Not true. The month will be in current locale of the app and if it is not set it could fallback to the jvm locale.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Internationalization (`i18n`) is handled out-of-the-box in almost every framework out there, then it's better to spend time on understand how to make it works than to write some unneded, buggy custom solution.

With Struts2, you must ensure to have:

- I18nInterceptor in your Interceptor Stack;
- I18nInterceptor defined in struts.xml: `<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />`;
- the localized, correctly named global.properties file for each locale you want to handle;
- the `request`_locale` parameter (if you have not changed the language in your browser) when calling your Actions, giving the I18nInterceptor the ability to hijack the request to the correct resource;
- an appropriate character encoding on your pages: `<%@ page contentType=”text/html;charset=UTF-8″ %>`.

Take a look at the guides available on the web too:

> http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-i18n-or-localization-example/
>
> http://www.2bloggers.com/2011/12/localization-i18n-in-struts2.html
>
> http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts/struts2.2.1/tags/i18ntag.html
>
> http://www.roseindia.net/struts/strutsinternationalization.shtml
>
> http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/I18N/internationalison-code.shtml