# Language changes back to default on refreshing the web page in amazon

Tags: struts2, amazon-ec2, multilingual

I have a project hosted in amazon, and it supports multiple languages. However, when i remove the locale from the url address, it fails to remember the language. However the same on local machine works fine. I guess it has some thing to do with multiple machines on amazon. I use Struts 2 framework. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Current language is stored in the session. So probably you have problems with session.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19546961/1654265 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/14256814/1654265